# A solution other than the Qualifier annotation in Spring

Tags: spring

I have a usecase for which I cannot use the Qualifier annotation (atleast according to my understanding) but I still need to resolve between two beans for Autowire. I cannot use the Qualifier because I dont know which implementation of FooBar will be used inside class Foo. Here is the setup I have:

```
class Foo
{
    @Autowired
    private FooBar a;
    public Foo(FooBar aa) {a = aa; }
}

interface FooBar
{}

class FooBarA implements FooBar
{}

class FooBarB implements FooBar
{}
```

spring config:

```
<bean id="beanA" class="FooBarA"/>
<bean id="beanB" class="FooBarB"/>

<bean id="bean1" class="Foo">
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="beanA"/></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="bean2" class="Foo">
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="beanB"/></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

This throws an error saying it cannot resolve the bean for the variable "a" in class "Foo" because there are two beans (beanA and beanB) even though I have explicitly specified which derivation of FooBar to use in each case of bean1 and bean2.

Comment: Did you intentionally exclude your `Foo` constructor or are you trying to inject a bean into a constructor which does not exist?

Comment: Missed the constructor. But the constructor is there in the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the constructor injection should look like this:

```
<constructor-arg>
    <ref bean="beanA"/>
</constructor-arg>
```

Or even just

```
<constructor-arg ref="beanA" />
```

Also move the `@Autowired` annotation from `FooBar` in `Foo` to the constructor since you're using constructor injection.

Alternatively, you could use field injection by doing this:

```
<bean id="bean1" class="Foo">
    <property name="a" ref="beanA" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Where can I use the qualifier? I cannot use the Qualifier inside class Foo because I don't know which of the implementations of FooBar will be used.

Comment: And I missed the word bean, it was a typo when writing the post. It exists in the original code.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't read the question correctly. A qualifier wouldn't work. Try using the constructor injection I showed above and remove the annotation.

Comment: Removed the Autowired annotation from FooBar and it worked! Thanks!